# gmon file not appearing after compiling a fortran 90 program with -pg

Tags: fortran, profiling, gprof

I have a Fortran program that I want to profile using `gprof`. What I do is I compile the files using the `-pg` option as follows (this is just a simple example):

```
program main

implicit none

real, dimension(100,100,100,100)  ::  A
integer                           ::  i,j,k,l

do i=1,100
do j=1,100
do k=1,100
do l=1,100
  A(i,j,k,l) = real( i+j+k+l ) 
end do
end do
end do
end do

print*, "END OF PROGRAM"

end program main
```

And then I compile manually:

```
gfortran -c main.f90 -pg
gfortran main.o -o prog -pg
```

But no `gmon` file appears as the program exits. Any ideas why this does not work?
I did install the binutils beforehand.

Versions:
`gfortran 5.1
binutils 2.25`
Operating system: OS X Yosemite

EDIT 21/07: I changed the example code following to a comment that was made

Comment: Could you try `-Og` instead of `-O2`? I'm not sure whether the latter interferes with debugging...

Comment: I tried, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: This is weird, your simple program is working fine in my case (`gfortran 5.1`). After running `prog` the `gmon.out` exists and can be interpreted by `gprof`... Which compiler version do you use?

Comment: I am also using `fortran 5.1`. I am wondering now if gprof is correctly installed. I simply downloaded `binutils 2.25`. I then did `./configure`, `make`, `make install`. And it looked like everything worked.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting no file, but you can be sure it will contain no samples, because it suspends sampling during I/O, and when it does sample it is only every 10ms, and the non-I/O part of your program takes maybe a microsecond, if that.

Comment: fair point, I just changed the example to something more time consuming

Comment: You probably can't see the deleted answer by @AlexanderVogt, but he says you also have to use `-pg` when linking. You might try moving it to a point earlier in both lines.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey He's doing that... I didn't see that from the answer due to a missing line continuation, but in the condensed example the option is there ;-) The location of `-pg` is irrelevant (to some extend), and the exact commands provided here with that snippet work fine on my machine...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: Yeah it's a puzzle. I was trying to be helpful, though it's hard to overcome my very [*dim view of gprof*](http://archive.is/9r927) :)